# ExpressJS Passport OIDC Callback Not Being Called

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js, openid-connect

I am new to the authentication system or OIDC. I am currently trying to integrate an OIDC tool called CILogon (https://www.cilogon.org/oidc) into a website I am building. Basically, it can redirect a user to a third-party login page via http://localhost:3000/auth, upon successful login, it will redirect the user to http://localhost:3000/home.

Now I want to get the login user information through callback, but the callback function doesn't seem to be called (e.g. I can't console.log the profile object:

```
passport.use(
  new OIDCStrategy(
    oidcConfig,
    (issuer, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, done) => {
      // This callback will be called after successful authentication

      console.log("profile: ", profile); // does not print

      return done(null, profile);
    }
  )
);
```

Below is the full code.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");

// auth
const config = require("./auth/config"); // saved on server only
const session = require("express-session");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const passport = require("passport");
const OIDCStrategy = require("passport-openidconnect").Strategy;

// Body parser to parse incoming and outgoing requests
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("server is up and running"));

// OIDC auth
const oidcConfig = {
  issuer: "https://cilogon.org",
  clientID: "xx123",
  clientSecret: "XXABC123",
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/home",
  authorizationURL: "https://cilogon.org/authorize",
  tokenURL: "https://cilogon.org/oauth2/token ",
  userInfoURL: "https://cilogon.org/oauth2/userinfo ",
};

// Generate a random session secret key
const secretKey = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString("hex");
app.use(
  session({
    secret: secretKey,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize()); // Initialize Passport middleware
app.use(passport.session()); // Enable session support for Passport

passport.use(
  new OIDCStrategy(
    oidcConfig,
    (issuer, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, done) => {

      console.log("profile: ", profile); // do not print

      console.log("here...");
      return done(null, profile);
    }
  )
);

app.get("/auth", passport.authenticate("openidconnect", { scope: "profile" })); // Initiate authentication

app.get(
  "/auth/callback",
  passport.authenticate("openidconnect", {
    successRedirect: "/home", // Redirect URL after successful authentication
    failureRedirect: "/login", // Redirect URL after failed authentication
  })
); // Callback URL for handling the OIDC provider's response

app.get("/home", async (req, res) => {
  console.log("home");
  const html = `<h1>Welcome to the home page!</h1>`; // Example HTML
  res.send(html);
});

app.get("/profile", (req, res) => {
  // Access the authenticated user's information from 'req.user'
  // Render the user's profile page
});

app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  // Log the user out and redirect to a logout page
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer to it - it seems I need to change "/auth/callback" to "/home" since I registered the callback URL to be "/home".